# MySQL Trigger with multiple IF statements not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm working on an 'audit_history' table that stores updates performed on my 'myTable' table. My code works with just the single IF statement that handles password updates. But as soon as I add another, I get the #1064 SQL Error. So I'm guessing it's something to do with my delimiters(?), but I just can't get it to work.

Any and all help would be great. Thanks.

```
IF (NEW.password <> OLD.password)
OR (NEW.password IS NOT NULL AND OLD.password IS NULL)
OR (NEW.password IS NULL AND OLD.password IS NOT NULL)
THEN
INSERT INTO myTable.audit_history 
VALUES (
    'update'
    , NULL
    , NOW()
    , @user_id
    , 'user'
    , 'password'
    , OLD.password
    , NEW.password);
END IF;

IF (NEW.landline <> OLD.landline)
OR (NEW.landline IS NOT NULL AND OLD.landline IS NULL)
OR (NEW.landline IS NULL AND OLD.landline IS NOT NULL)
THEN
INSERT INTO myTable.audit_history
VALUES (
    'update'
    , NULL
    , NOW()
    , @user_id
    , 'user'
    , 'landline'
    , OLD.landline
    , NEW.landline);
END IF;
```

I get this error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘IF (NEW.landline <> OLD.landline) OR (NEW.landline IS NOT NULL AND OLD.landline’ at line 17

Comment: Show the *full* trigger create sratement

Comment: Your error seems to be from another cause. The following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd94f/1) shows the code works as expected when creating the trigger.

Comment: I retyped it and it started to work. Still not sure why I got the error, but at least it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need BEGIN and END keywords for multiple statements

```
BEGIN
 IF (NEW.password &lt;&gt; OLD.password)
    OR (NEW.password IS NOT NULL AND OLD.password IS NULL)
    OR (NEW.password IS NULL AND OLD.password IS NOT NULL)
 THEN
    INSERT INTO myTable.audit_history 
    VALUES (
     'update'
    , NULL
    , NOW()
    , @user_id
    , 'user'
    , 'password'
    , OLD.password
    , NEW.password);
 END IF;

 IF (NEW.landline &lt;&gt; OLD.landline)
   OR (NEW.landline IS NOT NULL AND OLD.landline IS NULL)
   OR (NEW.landline IS NULL AND OLD.landline IS NOT NULL)
 THEN
  INSERT INTO myTable.audit_history
   VALUES (
    'update'
    , NULL
    , NOW()
    , @user_id
    , 'user'
    , 'landline'
    , OLD.landline
    , NEW.landline);
 END IF;
END;
```